# How can I dynamically reference cells containing dates in cubemember formula

Tags: excel, cube, olap-cube

I have converted my Cube Pivot table to formulas using OLAP Tools > Convert to formulas. 
The column labels are dates in UK format, which is fine. The CUBEMEMBER formula is as such:

`=CUBEMEMBER("Name of Cube","[Date].[Display Date].&[27/01/2017]")`

**This is the issue:**

If i **copy and paste the date 27/01/2017 in this exact format** (For example), and paste it above the cell that has the CUBEMEMBER formula, i can succesfully replace the member_expression part with that cell reference **in 2 ways**:

**One:** `=CUBEMEMBER("Name of Cube","[Date].[Display Date].&["&B8&"]")`
**Two:** `=CUBEMEMBER("Name of Cube",B8)`

I do not want to have to copy and paste dates, then link to those cells in order for it to work. I want to be able to link to a cell that already has a date in it. The difference is that its not in the EXACT same format as cubemember. Even if i copy the formats of the date, it does not work.

Any guidance??

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as numbers in Excel. The way to get the date as you want it is by using TEXT. With Swedish number formats in Windows the date can be shown as text by using this formula:
=TEXT(A1;"ÅÅÅÅ-MM-dd")
the "ÅÅÅÅ" part should probably be "yyyy" or "YYYY" for UK formats and could of course be "dd/MM/yyyy".